# Browser support for scrollTop of page

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, scrolltop

I want to get/set the `scrollTop` of the page. Apparently, some browsers only accept `document.body.scrollTop`, while others accept `document.documentelement.scrollTop`.

My question is, which browsers support what, and are there any browsers which doesn't support either, and a third term is needed?

Comment: There are nice sites out there who provide this information. Was visiting http://google.com to difficult??

Comment: @Jonasw Tried, but didn't get a clear answer. Maybe I'm searching with the wrong term? Do you know of a website that explains it?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp

Answer (score 0):

Browser support for `document.documentelement`: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_document_documentelement.asp

Browser support for `document.body`:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_body.asp

Hope the links are helpful for you :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for x.srollTop. I want to know what `x` is, and what are the browsers support for that.